Issue when making the player face the direction it's currently going
I'm trying to make the player face the direction it is going, not facing up & down but only on the X & Z axis.
Currently the player keeps facing only one direction, no matter which direction I'm moving, the player always faces forward and doesn't adjust to it. Making it really odd to watch, for example if I'm moving right, the players still faces forward.
That's the code I'm currently using for the movement & for making the player go where the camera is facing.
    public void Move()
{
    if (_inGravity)
    {
        float playerVerticalInput = Input.GetAxis("Vertical");
        float playerHorizontalInput = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");

        Vector3 forward = Camera.main.transform.forward;
        Vector3 right = Camera.main.transform.right;
        forward.y = 0;
        right.y = 0;
        forward = forward.normalized;
        right = right.normalized;

        Vector3 forwardRelativeVerticalInput = playerVerticalInput * forward;
        Vector3 rightRelativeHorizontalInput = playerHorizontalInput * right;

        Vector3 cameraRelativeMovement = forwardRelativeVerticalInput + rightRelativeHorizontalInput;

        transform.Translate(cameraRelativeMovement * _speed * Time.deltaTime, Space.World);

        bool isGrounded = Physics.CheckSphere(_groundCheck.position, _groundCheckRadius, _groundMask);

        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space) && isGrounded)
        {
            _rigidbody.AddForce(-_gravityBody.GravityDirection * _jumpForce, ForceMode.Impulse);
        }
    }


Please explain what the current issue is (what's going wrong).

Right, I edited it to be more clear.
Basically the issue is that right now, no matter which direction I'm moving, the player always faces forward and doesn't adjust to it. Making it really odd to watch, for example if I'm moving right, the players still faces forward

So where in your code do you do anything with a rotation of your object?

shouldn't this line :
transform.Translate(cameraRelativeMovement * _speed * Time.deltaTime, Space.World);
Do that? Or I misunderstood how it works?

No. Translation means a change in position only. It does not alter the object's orientation.

My bad, how can I alter the object orientation?

Have you looked at any samples? There are lots of Unity character control scripts online that show various strategies for this. In fact, there was one posted just yesterday, still on the top page of this site.

I tried using the code from the sample you linked, the player still doesn't face the direction.

You have to implement a "LookAt" function where you need to pass the movement direction vector as input. As output you will obtain a rotation angle needed to reach that movement direction vector. I'm pretty sure that in Unity there is a built-in function that do this :)

@Seo then you should edit your question to show how you attempted to integrate that sample into your code above, so that we can help you find your mistake. We can only guess what you did wrong if you don't show us.
